# Why does GHC use graph reduction instead of supercombinators?

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, compilation, functional-programming

Is graph reduction faster or better than supercombinators in any aspects?

Comment: Supercombinators (typically) do graph reduction, so I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: As far as I know, GHC does not use supercombinators at all. Supercombinators turns the problem into a tree reduction, not graph reduction.

Comment: I don't think that's true in the presence of general recursion. Besides, it's not like tree reduction is somehow "easier" than full graph reduction...

Comment: @Viclib, what would you say the difference is between tree reduction and graph reduction implementation-wise? The first is just a special case of the second isn't it?

Comment: Nobody serious does tree reduction.  Combinators have been doing graph reduction since David Turner suggested in in the early 70s.

Comment: I wouldn't be too surprised if @augustss did graph reduction with supercombinators before you were born ;-)

Comment: @molbdnilo It's a reasonable guess. :)

Answer (score 2):

Graph reduction is a technique for executing supercombinators.